# MySQL - Change date string to date type in column/database

Tags: mysql

I have a column called `dispatchdate`

It is currently storing dates as a string (varchar) format. 
It stores it as e.g. `16/07/2013`

How can I convert all my data in into date format without editing them all one by one?

Comment: Use the same solution as the linked answer, however you'll need to use the date format of `%d/%m/%Y` instead of `%d-%m-%Y`.  And no need for the PHP code -- use a plain old MySQL client!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution

```
UPDATE Table1
   SET dispatchdate = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dispatchdate, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d');

ALTER TABLE Table1 
      CHANGE dispatchdate dispatchdate date;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5562b/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks peterm - that seems to work on my test database - although I notice that it now displays the date as 2013-06-12 - is there anyway to get this as 12-06-2013?

Comment: see above comment - is there a way to change it from 2013-06-12 to 12-06-2013

Comment: Use `DATE_FORMAT(dispatchdate, '%d-%m-%Y')` for that